Example for $u\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus \{0\})\cap C^{1,\alpha}\cap L^2$
I am looking for an example for $u(x,y,z)\not=\text{ const}$, such that $$u\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus \{0\})\cap C^{1,\alpha}\cap L^2.\tag{1}$$
Does (1) really mean:
$$u\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus \{0\})\cap C^{1,\alpha}(x\in\{0\})\cap L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)\tag{2}$$
(1) showed up in a preprint by Diego Córdoba, Luis Martínez-Zoroa, Fan Zheng, titled "Finite time singularities to the 3D incompressible Euler equations for solutions in..."
Added
I think that I start to understand the notation in (1) now.
Figure 1 below is a 1D example of $\omega(x)$ mentioned in the reference above. This $\omega(x)$ is related to $u(x)$ via $\partial_x u(x)=H(w)(x)$ where $H(w)(x)$ is the Hilbert transform.
The $\omega(x)$ is composed of many compactly supported smooth spikes. Looking closely, theses spikes are smooth so $\omega(x)\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\})$.  But looking from a distance,the $\omega(x)$ curve as a whole is rough, and the roughness is characterized by $C^{\alpha}(\mathbb{R}), 0<\alpha<1$.

Thanks!

I would guess that $C^{1,\alpha}$ and $L^2$ are function spaces over all of $\mathbb R^3$. And you can obviously choose $u \equiv 0$.

Perhaps you may want to choose a non trivial map (you don't specified it). In that case, you can use smooth compactly supported map.

@gerw I forgot to say that $u\not= \text{ const}$. The part I do not understand is $u(x,y,z)\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus{0})$ and simoutaneously $u(x,y,z)\in C^{1,\alpha}(\mathbb{R}^3)$.  Here $0<\alpha<1$.

@Analyse300 You are right.  I added a figure from the reference and also my (half)understanding of the notation.  Am I right?  Thanks a lot!
